# PowerShell Get-Counter cmdlet returns internal error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get statistics about a virtual machine. The guest and host OS are both Windows Server 2012 R2, and the virtualisation is provided by Oracle VirtualBox 6.0.

I am trying to run the following PowerShell cmdlet, which is directly copy/pasted from the Microsoft Get-Counter documentation:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3
```

However it's returning the following error:

PS D:\ZEN\ZenScript\Powershell> Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3

Get-Counter : Internal performance counter API call failed. Error: c0000bb8.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 2 -Ma ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (:) [Get-Counter], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CounterApiError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetCounterCommand

PS D:\ZEN\ZenScript\Powershell>

On my local Windows 10 machine, this cmdlet executes normally. I have tried searching for the error string and code, but haven't found a solution yet. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this please?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this error if the system's locale of the Windows Server 2012 R2 is non-English.
On my Dutch machine for instance I need to do

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(*)\Percentage processortijd" -SampleInterval 2 -MaxSamples 3
```

You can check what the command should be by typing

```
(Get-Counter -ListSet 'Processor*').Counter
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. I have tried the (Get-Counter -ListSet 'Processor*').Counter command on two different Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machines. On the one that works, I do indeed get a result that says \Processor(*)\% Processor Time. However on the other VM that doesn't work, there are no counters that start with \Processor(*) -- only counters that start with \Processor Information(*). Any idea how to fix these missing counters?

Comment: @LogicalUnit The counters may be disabled in the registry or corrupted in some way. Perhaps a solution to that can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/2554336/how-to-manually-rebuild-performance-counters-for-windows-server-2008-6) or [here](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Performance-counters-are-not-working-or-missing-in-PerfMon)